# How to create flexible div items that break after the line?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create "shopping items" embedded in a `div` that have a certain fixed width and height. I know that you can do `display: inline !important;` to keep the `div`'s on one line.

However, how can I make it such that it breaks when the window size becomes smaller, preferably when the outer div is smaller?

Here is an illustration:
[image]

Here is what I tried:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">

                <div class="items">
                   <div class="item">
                       <p>Hello</p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="item">
                       <p>Hello</p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="item">
                       <p>Hello</p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="item">
                       <p>Hello</p>
                   </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

and css:

```
.items {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap !important;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap !important;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap !important;
    -o-flex-wrap: wrap !important;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap !important;
}
.item {
    width: 200px !important;
    height: 500px !important;
    margin: 10px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes see update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `flex` you can also set a breaking point *(without mediaquerie)* when boxes reaches 200px of width and also span them on the whole line:

*(bootstrap included in snippet , i do not really see troubles there)*

```css
.row {
  text-align: center;
}

.items {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
      -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
          justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
  /* with a breaking point at 200px width */
  min-width: 200px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  /* or without min-width nor flex, just:
  width:200px; it will wrap everytime needed and boxes will keep a static width */
  height: 150px;/* none or whatever*/
  margin: 10px 30px;/* whatever*/
  text-align: center;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="items">
      <div class="item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aha! Thanks. That worked. Actually, the problem is that I have multiple 'divs' inside the 'item'. That's why they break to another line. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Okay. Somehow, I figured it out and it works now perfectly. Just one more thing: how can I avoid that the last div spreads 100% in width. I want to keep it at a max width.

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So easy like that;

float: left;

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**. Its handles it easily.

Have a look at the snippet below (*resize your browser to see them in action*):

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eee;
  border: 3px solid #aaa;
  margin: 20px;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot... but still not working for me.. copied the code literally. Is there anything else to add to the .item? I have now that every item breaks.

Comment: @JohnAndrews It would be helpful if you can attach your code sample in the snippet, jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: @JohnAndrews It's working fine on my side. Here is the codepen of the code you've given - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBmabm (adjust the screen size an see it in action)

Comment: Weird as it works for me in the codepen. Maybe something to do with the boostrap css?

Comment: @JohnAndrews Yaks! Hope you are not missing `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">` in your `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`flex-basis`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis-property) to ensure your elements are always `200px` if it cannot grow nor shrink.

---

Using the `flex` shorthand property:

```
flex: 0 0 200px; /* 'flex-grow: 0' 'flex-shrink: 0' 'flex-basis: 200px' */
```

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 0 0 200px;  /* <'flex-grow'> <'flex-shrink'> <'flex-basis'> */
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: .5em;  /* Space between flex-items vertically*/
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px dashed grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="items">
      <div class="item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Notes:

- In the demo we use the recommended syntax, which is using
  the [**`flex`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property) shorthand property.
- Do not overuse the `!important` flag. It should not be needed in any of your classes.
- Removed vendor prefixes for demo simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other options I would suggest a look at isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/). The benefits of using this over a pure css solution would become more apparent if you decided to include any filtering or sorting of your shopping items.